# Is the right quotient of a regular language respect to another regular language a regular language?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

Will the language $\{w\in L_1\mid \exists v, wv\in L_2\}$ be regular if $L_1$ and $L_2$ regular languages?

Comment: Yes it is regular.

Comment: (Now if you want a better answer, you should try to improve your post: formatting, what you tried, your thoughts about the problem, …)

Comment: but if i dont know anything. please help to prove it that languagee is regular

Comment: Here's an introduction to formatting math on this site: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This might also be useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_of_a_formal_language

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13771/280596, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139389/83244

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Closure against right quotient with a fixed language](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1547/closure-against-right-quotient-with-a-fixed-language)

Comment: @xskxzr This seems a somewhat simpler operation than quotient. It takes the prefixes from $L_2$ and then intersects with $L_1$. For a quotient the definition is like $\{ w \mid \exists v\in L_1 , wv\in L_2\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix language of $L$ is the set of all prefixes of strings in $L$, $\{w\mid \exists v \in \Sigma^*, wv\in L\}$. In other words, it is the right quotient of $L$ with $\Sigma^*$, so it is certainly regular if $L$ is regular, by closure with right quotient.

A possibly simpler way to see this is to observe that you can construct a recogniser for the prefix language of $L$ by constructing the minimal DFA for $L$ and then making all states accepting.

Your language is the intersection of $L_1$ with the prefix language of $L_2$. Since regular languages are also closed with intersection, it must be regular if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are both regular.